# Data analysis of a 3D form in python

Tags: python, numpy, plot, 3d, volume

My question must have been answered already somewhere but i couldn't find it.

I have a binary numpy 3D array (shape =(512, 512, 304) ) in which there is a random form (labelled as 1). Any other point is labelled as 0.

Lets take for a simple example a sphere.

I want to plot this form on a 3D plot where we can see the sphere.

- I already tried 3D plot matplotlib but couldn't get the hand of it
- I used the interactive function from (ipywidgets) to print it slice by slice but that's not effetive

I also want to calculate the volume of the form (it may be a completely random poly polyhedron)

I am looking for advices more than answer
Thanks in advance

Comment: I used 3D voxels in matplotlib and its really slow. `pptk` viewer is much better tool for that, it can manipulate up to 100M points. Note that it doesn't support Python 3.8.

Comment: calculation of volume should be easy, just use `np.sum()`

Comment: Thks all for your help, the result was surprisingly easier than I expected. I finaly decided to go for printing with the interact widget with selection of an axis

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`voxels`](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/mpl_toolkits.mplot3d.axes3d.Axes3D.html#mpl_toolkits.mplot3d.axes3d.Axes3D.voxels), although it will be very slow if you try to run it with an array that big. You can for example plot only a 10% of the elements:

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
# Make a sphere
x, y, z = np.ogrid[-1:1:512j, -1:1:512j, -1:1:304j]
sphere = np.sqrt(x * x + y * y + z * z) < 0.5
# Make 3D axis
ax = plt.figure().add_subplot(projection='3d')
# Make voxels figures at 10% resolution
ax.voxels(filled=sphere[::10, ::10, ::10])
ax.figure.show()
```

Output:

[image: Output figure]

Answer (score 0):

One way to put it is to plot it using widgets:

```
def show_axial(image_array, slice):
   plt.imshow(img_array[:, :, mr_slice].T, cmap="gray")

interact(show_axial,img_array = fixed(im_arr), slice=widgets.IntSlider(max=im_arr.shape[2] - 1,min = 0))
```

That gaves a 2d plot with a slide bar that ranged between 0 to the image width and make it showable slide by slide.